# Mongo/Meteor Upsert without updating?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This may seem like a RTFM question, but I feel like I'm looking for something slightly different than `upsert`. I'm trying to reduce this if/else pattern:

```
let school = Schools.findOne(schoolData);
if (school) {
    school = school._id;
} else {
    school = Schools.insert(schoolData);
}

Classrooms.insert({'name':'fooClass', 'school':school})
```

*If the document exists, I just want the ID. I don't need to update it.*

For anyone wondering why, I'm using that ID as a reference in a document I'm inserting into a different collection.

Comment: What you are doing seems fairly reasonable to me. Its performance depends on how many times the `else` clause is reached (how often should a school be created). I would ask for the `_id` field only in order to save unneeded transport (in addition to potentially creating a minimalistic  query - querying by the minimal amount of unique data).

Comment: Great point about minimizing fields. It was just such a similar request to what `upsert` solved that I wondered if a native solution existed. So, there's no Mongo-centric approach to this pattern?

Comment: I don't think so. `update` does not return the affected documents.